# Matrix index notation and Einstein summation

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

Can I ask why these two expressions are not equal?

$$\begin{align}A_{ij}V^j&\ne V^kA_{ki}\\A_{ij}B^{ij}&\ne A^i{}_jB^j{}_i\end{align}$$

Comment: In both cases, it's because matrices are not in general symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

First notice that tensors with two upper or two lower indices are not matrices, in that they represent linear transformations;  they represent bilinear transformations. Tensors representing matrices have one upper and lower index.

Now in the first expression, if the tensor $A$ was symmetric, so that $A_{ij} = A_{ji}$, we would have:

> $A_{ij} V^j = A_{ji} V^j = V^j A_{ji} = V^k A_{ki}$

Where in the last step we relabelled. Thus, in general,  it is when the tensor is not symmetric that the two expressions are unequal.

Likewise if the tensor $B$ is symmetric, then we get:

$A_{ij}B^{ij} = A_{ij} B^{ji} = A^i{}_j B^j{}_i $

Hence, again in general,  it is when either tensor $A$ or $B$ are not symmetric that the two expressions are unequal.